# How can I add radio button and submit button in a drupal view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to add radio button in my drupal *view* ?
I need to make a table of users and set for each of them one status(present,absent,delayed,...) by use of radio buttons, and A button under the table to save these statuses.
So how can I change *view*?

Answer (score 0):

Mohsen,

Maybe Views Bulk Operations module can help you. You can download it at http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations.

Comment: Is it possible to put a form in each field, and use Views Bulk Operations module?

Comment: but VBO is not sufficient for my purpose, I don't want to edit this module.

Answer (score 0):

I used embed form module to add some radio buttons in my view. and now I must implement submission.

Answer (score -1):

I wish I new.

I'm currently playing with hook_views_data to create a relationship within Views between my table and a node. This works ok.

I just need to work out how to make this data submittable from within the View.

If I work it out I'll let you know.